# InstallShield 2010 with license - no license for automatic build system (CI) as Windows service

Tags: build-process, continuous-integration, hudson, installshield

I really need help here.

We are using CI build-process (Hudson) as an automated build system using Msbuild.
The CI run in Apache Tomcat 6 that run under the credentials of a domain user (not a local Windows user ).

Every time the CI try to build an InstallShield project (using isproj files) we get a license error message:
" C:\Program Files\MSBuild\InstallShield\2010\InstallShield.targets(62,3): error : -7159: The product license has expired or has not yet been initialized. You must launch the IDE to configure the product license in order to proceed.
  C:\Program Files\MSBuild\InstallShield\2010\InstallShield.targets(62,3): error : Exception Caught".

If I log in to the same machine with the same domain user credentials and build the InstallShield project there is a license and it is working well.

Adding the user to the local Users group doesn't help (no license).
Adding the user to the local Administrators group helps and it is working.

We do not want the user to be in the local Administrators group - for various reasons.

What do I need to do to make it work?
Do I need to add permissions to the use?

Help will be highly appreciated.

Gilad

Comment: Are you still looking for other reasons to get rid of IS? If you are targeting only Windows just use NSIS.

Answer (score 0):

Is your build calling isSaBld.exe or isCmdBld.exe?  InstallShield changed their policy in 2010 so that the standalone build functionality (isSaBld) is only available with a top-tier license.  In previous versions it was usable in Pro too.  Maybe this has something to do with it?

We have a similar build system - Hudson in tomcat 6, IS2010, but with Ant scripts - and calling IsCmdBld.exe is working for us.

Comment: Thank you sjohnston for your input.

We are not using isSaBld.exe or isCmdBld.exe directly.
We are using msbuild with InstallShield "InstallShield.targets" and "InstallShield.Tasks.dll", I do not know if it uses isSaBld.exe or isCmdBld.exe.

Gilad

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Hudson [as a service](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Installing+Hudson+as+a+Windows+service), try running the service as an administrator. But you need to make sure the administrator succees to build the project from the InstallShield IDE first.

Answer (score 0):

> We do not want the user to be in the local Administrators group

To my knowledge there is no way around this requirement. InstallShield's product licensing runs low-level system checks that require that the running user be in the Administrators group to succeed. That's why when you start the InstallShield IDE the UAC prompt appears. That way they can verify that the license they granted you hasn't been moved to a different machine. Without being privy to exactly how they do this, imagine e.g. direct disk sector access, CPU serial number reads, hard drive firmware access, etc. You just can't do those things without Admin rights.

However to ensure that every build can be reproduced, a build machine should be sacrosanct, and access to it should only be granted to trusted build users. It's standard for them to be Administrators on the build machine.

Can you give more details about why you need to keep the user from being an Administrator? That would enable us to give you better input.